# How do you url indexOf with multiple options?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to say that if a URL ends in X, then I want a div to be injected onto the site. However, there are multiple X's.

```
var adfc = '$0.00';
if (url.indexOf('YHOPT20T', 'YR20B', 'YR20T') > 0) { {
          adfc = '$10.00';
      }
if (adfc == '$0.00') {
      if (shipsfree == true && returnsfree == true) {
              document.write('<div style="padding-top:12px;"><span class="shipNote">FREE SHIPPING & FREE RETURN</span></div>');
              sizeadviceshow = true;
          }
      else if (shipsfree == true && returnsfree == false) {
              document.write('<div style="padding-top:12px;"><span class="shipNote">FREE SHIPPING</span></div>');
          }
      }
      else {
          document.write('<div style="padding-top:12px;"><span style="font-size:12px; font-weight:normal; color:#AA1E37; cursor:pointer; line-height:18px;">' + adfc + ' Additional Freight Charge</span></div>');
      }
```

How would I accomplish targeting multiple sections in the code?

Comment: `indexOf(…) > 0` doesn't test whether the URL *ends* with the argument string. What exactly do you need?

Comment: @Bergi I'm sorry, I'm unable to post all the code. I receive an error. How would I accomplish stating that its the end?

Comment: Use [`endsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith)… I just meant to say that your `indexOf` approach doesn't even work with single values - it checks whether the search part is anywhere in the string but at its start. To check for multiple values, use `['YHOPT20T', 'YR20B', 'YR20T'].some(x => url.endsWith(x))`

Comment: @Bergie I think I understand what you're saying. To clarify, the code would look like:

if (url.indexOf(['YHOPT20T', 'YR20B', 'YR20T'].some(x => url.endsWith(x)) {
              adfc = '$10.00';
          }

Comment: No, drop the `indexOf` call completely. It's just `if ([…].some(…)) { … }`